# Understanding stack and base pointer Y86 - linked List sum

Tags: assembly, y86

Note : This is for a class. I'm just trying to understand how the rsp and rbp work so I can understand what part of my code is messed up. Sorry I'm new to this . Thanks for any help.

So I'm writing Y86 code to find sum of nodes of linked list

```
        .pos 0
    init:   irmovq  Stack, %rsp     # Set up stack pointer
    rrmovq  %rsp,%rbp       # Set up base pointer
    irmovq  ele1,%rdi
    irmovq  $18, %r8        #Note 1 : unsure of what this should be
    call    rsum_list        # Execute main program
    halt                    # Terminate program


  # Sample linked list
    .align 8
  ele1:   .quad 0x00
    .quad ele2
  ele2:   .quad 0x0b0
    .quad ele3
  ele3:   .quad 0xc00
    .quad 0

        # int sum_list(list_ptr ls)
  rsum_list:  pushq   %rbp
        rrmovq  %rsp,%rbp
        xorq    %rax,%rax       # val = 0
        subq %r8, %rsp              #subtract constant from rsp , not sure why we need to do this -> saw this in x86 code
        rmmovq %rdi, -18(%rbp)      #move ls to -18(%rbp)
        andq %rdi, %rdi             #check if 0   
        je End
        mrmovq -18(%rbp), %rax
        mrmovq (%rax), %rax            #rax gets ls->val
        rmmovq %rax, -10(%rbp)         #the val obtained is stored in -10(%rbp)
        mrmovq -18(%rbp), %rax         #rax becomes ls again
        mrmovq 8(%rax), %rax          # rax gets ls-> next
        rmmovq %rax, %rdi             #this is copied to rdi for next recursive call
        call rsum_list
        rmmovq %rax, -8(%rbp)          #rax will contain ans from recursive call
        mrmovq -10(%rbp), %rdx       #retrieve ans. of current node from -10(%rbbp) , where we stored it before recursion
        mrmovq -8(%rbp), %rax      
        addq %rdx, %rax           #adding

  End :
       rrmovq %rbp, %rsp
       popq %rbp
       nop                     # makes sure stop in 31 steps
       ret
```

I suspect I'm making a mistake in storing values on the stack somewhere that is being messed up due to recursion. Sorry but I really don't undderstand this and want to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

What it should give me in rax finally : 0x0000cba
What I'm getting is 0x0000040

[image]

Comment: Please explain the problem you’re having. What is it doing, how is it wrong, what should happen etc. This will help us understand what’s happening and find the problem.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen does that help?

Comment: `$18` is probably supposed to be `$0x18`, so the stack stays 16-byte aligned.  (`0x10`).  Decimal `18` would be a very weird amount of stack space to reserve, but hex `0x18` makes sense.

Comment: When debugging, try to find the point at which things stop being what you expect.  Single-step and watch memory change, or set breakpoints later.  You presumably understand the starting state, and you know the end state doesn't match what you expect.  You can try to binary search to find the spot in the middle.  In your case, watch out for overwriting data on the stack when `push` writes to the same address you're accessing relative to `%rbp`, if you didn't subtract enough from `%rsp`.  See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: For your comment on "not sure why we need to do this": The x86 calling convention requires a program to only use stack that is above the stack-pointer. So, if you want to allocate storage for local variables, you subtract that amount from the stack-pointer.  This was so that ancient operating systems could safely handle interrupts on the stack of whatever process was running when the interrupt arrived.  But you're writing for the AMD64 calling convention, which allows you to use 128 bytes of data *below* the stack pointer---this is called the 'red zone' if you want to google more.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: it's not about "ancient operating systems", it's about signal handler semantics.  The x86-64 Windows calling convention doesn't provide a red-zone, only the better-designed x86-64 SysV calling convention has that.  (And only in user-space: the kernel code model doesn't have a red-zone because interrupts use the kernel stack, and there's no way to stop them from pushing their return info right below `rsp`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/red-zone/info). Anyway, all of this is irrelevant for recursive functions: you have to avoid synchronously clobbering your data yourself :P

Comment: @PeterCordes: no argument here.  I just wanted to give a pointer to the notion of "different calling conventions and ABI requirements" and at least one historical motivation in answer to his question of "why do people do this?".  I was not aware the Linux kernel doesn't do a red-zone; that fact is quite timely.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to partially overwrite your stored value from the current node with the result of your recursive call.  I've added asterisks to the relevant lines below:

```
*rmmovq %rax, -10(%rbp)         #the val obtained is stored in -10(%rbp)
 mrmovq -18(%rbp), %rax         #rax becomes ls again
 mrmovq 8(%rax), %rax          # rax gets ls-> next
 rmmovq %rax, %rdi             #this is copied to rdi for next recursive call
 call rsum_list
*rmmovq %rax, -8(%rbp)          #rax will contain ans from recursive call
 mrmovq -10(%rbp), %rdx       #retrieve ans. of current node from -10(%rbbp) , where we stored it before recursion
 mrmovq -8(%rbp), %rax
```

Note that the two storage locations are only 2 bytes apart, though the values written are 8-bytes long.  Given Intel's little endian storage convention, writes will align as follows, where the columns give the placement of the three writes that occur at a given recursion depth (with `ans` denoting the answer from the recursive call)

```
RBP: 
 -1:                         ans(MSB)     
 -2:                         ans     
 -3:           ls->val(MSB)  ans     
 -4:           ls->val       ans     
 -5:           ls->val       ans     
 -6:           ls->val       ans     
 -7:           ls->val       ans     
 -8:           ls->val       ans(LSB)
 -9:           ls->val     
-10:           ls->val(LSB)     
-11: ls(MSB)                
-12: ls                
-13: ls                
-14: ls                
-15: ls                
-16: ls                
-17: ls                
-18: ls(LSB)
```

Unfortunately, this alone shouldn't have produced your 0x40, so there's something else wrong.